# Symfony 2 object with array of objects, how to access them?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, object, doctrine-orm

I have 3 Symfony2 entities that are related in the following way:

1. A Vehicle with Plate Number, make, model. Also the vehicle has many Jobs and Fuel Purchases
2. Job has a method that gives the total distance of the job (using odometer at the start and odometer at the end of the job.
3. Fuel Purchase has liters, fuel price and a cost method.

Is wanted to render a table report that has Vehicle Plate number, Total Distance, Total Fuel, Fuel cost, Km/L, Total Jobs all that based on a period of time.
Is also wanted to do a traditional query to the database that does all that and I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288988/symfony-2-join-not-working-doctrine-and-mysql) question. You can see some of the actual objects there. But if I am not wrong the Symfony2 philosophy is to use the vehicle object that has all this objects to do it. What do you think is the best way to do this?
Just I cant manage to for instance go up and down the array of objects. I have tried this:

```php
class ReportsController extends Controller
{
    public function renderAction(Request $request)
    {
        $vehicles = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('TeamERPTransportBundle:Vehicle')->findAll();
        $countVehicles = 0;
        $countJobsXVehicle = array();
        foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle)
        {            
            $VehicleJobs = $vehicle->getJobs();
            $countJobsXVehicle[$countVehicles] = 0;
            $countVehicles++;
            //This piece of code gives the error
            foreach ($VehicleJobs as $VehicleJob)
            {
               $countJobsXVehicle[$countVehicles]++;
            }
            //I am planing to do the same for Fuel purchase
            //$VehicleRefuels = $vehicle->getFuelPurchaces();
            //foreach ($VehicleRefuels)
        }
    }
}
```

With this I get this error:
`ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: vehicles in D:\Web\wamp\www\team\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister.php line 1753`

How do I make it work? 
Thank you for your help!

Edit:
I have also tried this:

```
class ReportsController extends Controller
{
public function renderAction(Request $request)
{
    $vehicles = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TeamERPTransportBundle:Vehicle')->findAll();

    $countVehicles = 0;
    $countJobsXVehicle[] = 0;

            foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle)
            {     
                    $VehicleJobs  = new ArrayCollection();
                    $VehicleJobs[]  = $vehicle->getJobs();
                    $countJobsXVehicle[$countVehicles] = $this->VehicleJobs($VehicleJobs);          
                    //$VehicleRefuels = $vehicle->getFuelPurchaces();
                    //foreach ($VehicleRefuels)
                    $countVehicles++;                        
            }

}
    return $this->render('TeamERPTransportBundle:Transport:report.html.twig', array('vehicles' => $vehicles,
        'countJobsXVehicle' => $countJobsXVehicle,
        'countVehicles' => $countVehicles,
        'render' => $graph));
}
private function VehicleJobs (ArrayCollection $VehicleJobs){
    $countJobsXVehicle = 0;
    foreach ($VehicleJobs as $VehicleJob)
    {
        $countJobsXVehicle++;
        //var_dump($VehicleJob);
    }  
    return $countJobsXVehicle;
}
}
```

and it works but it does not behave the way is expected.
[image: Report Table]
the Entity clases are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288988/symfony-2-join-not-working-doctrine-and-mysql).

Comment: I don't see any array calling the `vehicles` index in your code. Are you sure the code in your question is the code at line 1753?

Comment: @n.1 I don't really know what you mean, maybe because I am too nob. Check out the edition of the question.

Comment: I was wondering why the error message mentions `vehicles` whereas there is no variable with this name.

Answer (score 0):

I would create these totals functions in the VehicleRepository that queried for jobs/ totalFuel/ and totalDistance partials (see doctrine's partials [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html)) and return an Array result [getArrayResult](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html), then I would do a simple array count using foreach vehicle like you did above. Then do your findAll result, returning joined objects Vechicle, etc.--pass all these to your template. 
Let us know a little more about these totals you're seeking and I can be more specific.

Comment: can you post your template? I questioned your fuelPurchace Entity association on your linked question.

Comment: Thank you I have sorted it out using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369285/symfony-2-join-not-working-doctrine) method. at the end the problem was not in my query method, but in my entities.